# Visual Studio publish doesn't report errors

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I have a WCF web service using Visual Studio 2015.  If I have a compile error in C# code, when I publish the web service (to a file location) the "build" will succeed, and continue through a successful publish:

`========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 1 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Publish: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========`

If I then deploy to an IIS web server and call the web service there, the call fails and returns a page describing the compilation error.

When publishing, the output in VS starts with `Build started:` but apparently it isn't really doing a build because any build would have failed, and in fact if I do a build instead of publish, it does report the error(s).  Do I have to remember to build before publishing to check for errors, or is there a way to get it to really for realz compile the code?

Comment: Please check your output from View > Output this will explain the details

Comment: The Output view displays no errors; everything appears successful there.  I can switch to Error List to check for errors, but that is a step I have to remember to do every time, and VS is not giving me any prompt that it's necessary.  I have no problem figuring out what the error is, the problem is that Visual Studio reports that everything is successful when it's not.

Comment: "and use the web service, it fails with a compilation error." - part makes no sense. There is no VS involved after publishing to web server. Please [edit] to clarify what you actually see.

Comment: `If I then push to a server`? what server? IIS?

Comment: I deploy to a server on IIS, and when hitting a web service endpoint, the result is an error page describing the compilation error.

Answer (score 1):

If solution has many projects then try building them one at a time.

Try below steps:

- Restart Visual Studio.
- Restart Computer
- Rebuild all
- Clean Solution then Rebuild All

Also you can check below

Setting the MSBuild project build output verbosity (in Options > Projects and Solutions > Build and Run setting area) to "Diagnostic" as shown below. This then showed that the custom action was what had failed.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/saraford/2008/10/07/did-you-know-you-can-configure-the-msbuild-verbosity-in-the-output-window-329/

Comment: If I set output to Diagnostic, VS just hangs in the middle of build (tried twice).  At Minimal, Normal, and Detailed levels, the build completes without errors despite a syntax error in the source.